# stubbing a function using jest

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, sinon

is there a way to stub a function using jest API? 
I'm used to working with sinon stub, where I can write unit-tests with stubs for any function call coming out of my tested unit-
http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/

for example-

```
sinon.stub(jQuery, "ajax").yieldsTo("success", [1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: Did you found how to solve this with Jest? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 51):

With `jest` you should use [`jest.spyOn`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname):

```js
jest
  .spyOn(jQuery, "ajax")
  .mockImplementation(({ success }) => success([ 1, 2, 3 ]));
```

Full example:

```js
const spy = jest.fn();
const payload = [1, 2, 3];

jest
  .spyOn(jQuery, "ajax")
  .mockImplementation(({ success }) => success(payload));

jQuery.ajax({
  url: "https://example.api",
  success: data => spy(data)
});

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(payload);
```

You can try live example on `codesandbox`: https://codesandbox.io/s/018x609krw?expanddevtools=1&module=%2Findex.test.js&view=editor

Comment: const spy = jest
  .spyOn(jQuery, "ajax")
  .mockImplementation(({ success }) => success(payload));

Comment: @emj365 I've just tried this way and received `TypeError: success is not a function`.

You can play with it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/kkq2377ll5. Just uncomment 12-14 lines.

Comment: i tried jest.spyOn.mockImplementation() it's work but not cover test coverage, since sinon stub yields cover test coverage. am i missing something here  ?

Answer (score 5):

Jest [provides](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html) jest.fn(), which has some basic mocking and stubbing functionality.

If you're experienced and comfortable with sinon you could still create Jest-based tests which use sinon test doubles. However you'll lose the convenience of built in Jest matchers such as `expect(myStubFunction).toHaveBeenCalled()`.

Comment: Thanks. Is it restorable like sinon.stub.restore? The doc examples aren't really clear for me. It seems like you can only mock an entire module and then a func in it + they mention some sort of auto mocking option?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to sub out jquery entirely by using `mockReturnValue` and jquery's `$.Deferred`. This allowed me to manually resolve my ajax calls and then the rest of the function would continue (and any chaining of `.done()` or `.success()` etc would execute.

Example:

```js
const deferred = new $.Deferred();
$.ajax = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(deferred);

myClass.executeAjaxFunction();

const return_val = 7;

deferred.resolve(return_val)
```

Then if I have a function like

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/myurl'
}).done((val) => {
    window.property = val;
});
```

The following test will pass

```js
it('should set my property correctly', () => {
    expect(window.property).toBe(7);
});
```

Of course- you can skip the deferred part of this answer if you are trying to stub a non-jquery function. I came across this question that dealt with ajax and came up with this solution as a way to test a function that executes actions after an ajax call is complete using `Jest`.

Answer (score 2):

Doing following two thing, got it working for me.

1. Adding `__esModule:true` fixed this issue for me.

   `jest.mock('module',()=>({ __esModule: true, default: jest.fn() }));`
2. Moving the mocking part before the describe. (Just after the imports.)

   //moving it to before the describe ->
   `jest.mock(...); describe('', ...);`

Hope this helps somebody.