# stub method in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocha.js, chai

I have a method loadDataFromLocalStorage() in one of my react component.

loadDataFromLocalStorage() will get the item from localStorage and return it.

So I am writing unit test cases for myFunc().

```
myFunc(){
    var data = loadDataFromLocalStorage()();
    if(data) {
      return true;
    }    
  }
```

When I tried to run my test I see that loadDataFromLocalStorage() is not retrieving the data from localStorage. So I guess tests wont be able to access localStorage and return the data.

So as an alternative I need to stub the value for 
loadDataFromLocalStorage() and return it so that myFunc can be unit tested.

Please advise..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stubbing a function using jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259086/stubbing-a-function-using-jest)

Comment: [This answer about mocking within a module might help you as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486015/6320039)

Comment: Where this `loadDataFromLocalStorage` comes from? it is important for the stubing method.

Comment: @felixmosh loadDataFromLocalStorage is a method defined outside of myFunc()

Comment: How do u get the ref for it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution, the structure of the file directory:

```sh
.
├── __mocks__
│   └── loadDataFromLocalStorage.ts
├── index.spec.ts
├── index.ts
└── loadDataFromLocalStorage.ts

1 directory, 4 files
```

Your original function `loadDataFromLocalStorage.ts`:

```js
function loadDataFromLocalStorage() {
  return () => {
    return '';
  };
}

export default loadDataFromLocalStorage;
```

You use `loadDataFromLocalStorage` function in your `myFunc`:

```js
import loadDataFromLocalStorage from './loadDataFromLocalStorage';

const someModule = {
  myFunc() {
    const data = loadDataFromLocalStorage()();
    console.log(`data: ${data}`);
    if (data) {
      return true;
    }
  }
};

export { someModule };
```

Mock `loadDataFromLocalStorage` function in `__mocks__` directory:

```js
function loadDataFromLocalStorage() {
  return () => {
    return 'mock data';
  };
}

export default loadDataFromLocalStorage;
```

The unit test:

```js
jest.mock('./loadDataFromLocalStorage.ts');
import { someModule } from './';

describe('someModule', () => {
  it('t1', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const actualValue = someModule.myFunc();
    expect(actualValue).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/mock-function/questions-57494989/index.spec.ts
  someModule
    ✓ t1 (10ms)

  console.log src/mock-function/questions-57494989/index.ts:6
    data: mock data

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.44s, estimated 3s
```